# how to fix xmlhttprequest function problem when inserting data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

my code works only if i add this code:

```
document.write(str);
```

which open a new page and write in it insert data in database

but if i try to the code without it like this :

```
    function addcourse2(str,cn)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
//document.write(str);  
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 

                       alert('response:'+xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else {

                       alert('failure!');
            }

};

    xmlhttp.open("GET","tpages/addcourse2.php?q="+str+"&p="+cn,true);

     xmlhttp.send();
}
```

here i get alert message failure and nothing gets inserted into database
i need and explanation to this a way to fix it

Comment: Please format your code and tell us the value of `str` and `cn`

Comment: You should check what the status value is.  If it is 500, you should check your error logs for an error message.

Comment: @Wendelin str is the user id  cn is the value of a text box(String)

Comment: @PatrickQ the status is 0

Comment: @thestalker 0 is not a valid HTTP status code

Comment: If the server isn't returning HTTP 200, then there's a server-side problem and all this Javascript code is irrelevant. What does your browser's network inspector tell you?

Comment: @PatrickQ maybe cause the readystate is 1?

Comment: @thestalker Huh??  I meant within your `else`.  Instead of just a useless 'failure' message.  The only way you get there is if the readyState is 4.  Anyway, as miken32 said, look at your network inspector and see what it says.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah sorry i changed that in may code after displaying it here i'll edit it

Comment: in the network the status is always showing as 200

Comment: as it fails to insert data into the database i noticed after i used alert(xmlhttp.status) that it's kind off in a loop where the state is changing after each alert message but the page refreshes before it can do it, and when i add the document.write(str) that get's me to anew page i get 4 messages in each of the alert messages i notice how the state is changing from 1 to 2 to 3 then it reach 4 and the data get's inserted successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your comments i understand that the page is refreshing after you click the button before the state is reaching 4 then this is the button code to prevent it from refreshing

add return false;

```
<button "onclick='addcourse2("value1","value2");return false;'>add course</button>
```

Comment: tyvm this fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to describe.

Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open.

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write*

So, this AJAX script with document.write work as from new page and each case calls to URL ""tpages/addcourse2.php?q="+str+"&p="+cn"

If commented document.write Then browser may be cached URL and browser read from cache and doesn't call same URL. So, you can use unique URL string and test so.

Also, may be was an other case.

Comment: the above code worked for me. the page refreshing onclick was the reason the state isn't reaching 4 ty for trying to help i was stuck on this for 6 hours for 2 words code kinda embarrassing